# Array not in square shape

Tags: modeling

When i increase the count. The shape of array is not square. The corner are getting curve shape & the shape of the mesh some have square some tilted etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Curve modifier inevitably leads to some deformation.
In this case, try the following.

1. Change curve spline type to Bezier
2. Move the handles a bit closer (that will correct the geometry)
3. Increase the curve resolution to 128 (that will improve corners)

*Change Spline Type to Bezier and move the handles a bit.*

[image]

*Increase Curve resolution to 128 to improve corners*

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The corner mesh not in shape. Look little triangular in shape

Comment: Yes, the curve modifier has some limits.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click and select your model and move it to the position you want. (Preferable at the corner of the square)
2. Select *Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*
3. Select *Add > Empty > Sphere* (Or any other shape)
4. Pick your model and add an *Array* modifier. Create a straight array by choosing "Fixed Count" option with "Factor X=2" and "Count=10" values
5. Add a second *Array* modifier to your model. For the second *Array* modifier select "Object Offset" option and enter "4" on "Count" line. Select "Empty" from "Object" dropdown menu.
6. Click and select the Empty on the scene. Rotate it 90° on the Z axis.

[image]